# how to test object methods (exercise)

Tags: scala, class

As part of an exercise I am writing an API to generate random numbers. 
This is the code that I have and I would like to test the `notNegativeInt` function.

How can I do that?

(here the full solution https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/blob/master/answers/src/main/scala/fpinscala/state/State.scala )

```
import java.util.Random

object chapter6 {
  println("Welcome to the Scala worksheet")       //> Welcome to the Scala worksheet

  trait RNG {
    def nextInt: (Int, RNG) // Should generate a random `Int`. We'll later define other functions in terms of `nextInt`.
  }

  object RNG {
    // NB - this was called SimpleRNG in the book text
    case class Simple(seed: Long) extends RNG {
      def nextInt: (Int, RNG) = {
        val newSeed = (seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFL // `&` is bitwise AND. We use the current seed to generate a new seed.
        val nextRNG = Simple(newSeed) // The next state, which is an `RNG` instance created from the new seed.
        val n = (newSeed >>> 16).toInt // `>>>` is right binary shift with zero fill. The value `n` is our new pseudo-random integer.
        (n, nextRNG) // The return value is a tuple containing both a pseudo-random integer and the next `RNG` state.
      }
    }
    // We need to be quite careful not to skew the generator.
    // Since `Int.Minvalue` is 1 smaller than `-(Int.MaxValue)`,
    // it suffices to increment the negative numbers by 1 and make them positive.
    // This maps Int.MinValue to Int.MaxValue and -1 to 0.
    def nonNegativeInt(rng: RNG): (Int, RNG) = {
      val (i, r) = rng.nextInt
      (if (i < 0) -(i + 1) else i, r)
    }



  }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test only the nonNegativeInt method, you could provide a mock implementation of RNG that provides the values you want to test when nextInt is called.
For example, there are 2 possible branches in the nonNegativeInt, so you should provide a RNG instance that gives a negative number and another one that provides a positive number.

```
class MyRNG(val num:Int) extends RNG {
  self: RNG => 
    def nextInt: (Int, RNG) = (num, this)
}
```

With this RNG mock you could test your nonNegativeInt method, creating a MyRNG with the desired value you want to test against.

For this particular case, you can also omit the self reference:

```
class MyRNG(val num:Int) extends RNG {
  def nextInt: (Int, RNG) = (num, this)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please explain me the syntax `self: RNG => 
    def nextInt: (Int, RNG) = (num, this) ` that is not very clear to me

Comment: In this case, you could omit it, but if you want to read further: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/explicitly-typed-self-references.html

Comment: But, it's basically enabling a reference to yourself with another type (obviously higher in the object hierarchy). Sometimes, I use the explicit typed self reference to point that I'm using this

Comment: In this way I am able to test the `nextInt` but not the `nonNegativeInt` function. The scala worksheet does  not compile if I add `def nonNegativeInt(rng: RNG)` in the trait class

Comment: Actually, no, this way you are able to test any function that takes a RNG. for example you can define a test like the following:
val myRnd = new MyRNG(3)
RNG.nonNegativeInt(myRnd) == (3, myRnd)
val myRndNeg = new MyRNG(-3)
RNG.nonNegativeInt(myRndNeg) == (3, myRndNeg)